# Applying trained SVM to completely new data, retrieving labels

Tags: matlab, svm

Say I have a simple implementation for SVM-classification as for instance:

```
%# train an SVM model over training instances    
svmModel = svmtrain(meas(trainIdx,:), groups(trainIdx), ...       
             'Autoscale',true, 'Showplot',false, 'Method','QP', ...        
             'BoxConstraint',2e-1, 'Kernel_Function','rbf', 'RBF_Sigma',1);   

%# test using test instances  
pred = svmclassify(svmModel, meas(testIdx,:), 'Showplot',false);  

%# evaluate and update performance object
cp = classperf(cp, pred, testIdx);
```

Now I want the following: Train the classifier on one dataset, where I have labels, and then apply it to another dataset from which I do not know the labels at all. Is this possible? If so, would I use the line where the prediction ("pred") is made to classify the unlabelled data (or alternatively optimize parameters based on my labeled data and use the best model's prediction on the test data)?

Comment: Yes, that is how an svm is used. You train with data with known ground truth and then apply to data without known ground truth.

Comment: How is then the accuracy calculated for the test set, if there are no labels? Do you also know specifically for this implementation where I can retrieve predicted labels? Thank you

Comment: You have to have labels for the test set to determine accuracy on the test set.

Comment: Is there any other procedure or measure I can use to determine classification performance if I don't (yet) have any labels for these?

Comment: You should have at least one set of data which is fully labeled. To ensure good generalization you want to split that labeled set into at least two parts, a training set, and a test set. Train the SVM using only the training set then verify that it works well on the testing set. Better yet, partition the labeled set into 3 sets. Training, Validation, and Test. Train on training. Check to see how well it works on validation. Adjust model parameters and repeat. When you are happy with the performance on the validation then run on the test set. The validation set further helps avoid overfitting.

Comment: The idea is that once you are confident that the SVM generalizes well then you can be justified in trusting the results of the classifier on novel and unlabeled data to the same degree of accuracy that classifier performed on the test set.

Comment: I understand, many thanks. But that still seems quite a leap of faith given my unlabelled data could be quite different in nature. So there is no direct performance measures for this dataset I understand at all?

Comment: Yes, bias in the datasets is a big problem. Unfortunately if the labeled data is likely to be very different from the unlabeled data then you can't trust the results of the SVM. You may be interested in some popular research topics like domain adaptation and transfer learning which in some ways attempt to address these issues.

Comment: thanks for all the feedback